# Is there a public database of banned users, ip addresses, or emails?

Tags: database, block, public

Out of curiosity, is there is a public block list for abusive online users across the internet?

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of lists but they're mostly useless because they all represent the arbitrary opinion of the list maintainer.

Also the user(s) associated with particular IP addresses and ranges change. They're routinely bought, sold and reassigned.

Some people block entire countries that they don't need to deal with, but this really just reduces background noise and doesn't actually help much.

Comment: Then how do I block users on a specific computer?

Comment: If you know the IP address of a machine you don't want to talk to, you would add it to whatever firewall you're using, or add code to your application to ignore requests from that address.

Comment: Just a note that this is more or less useless. It requires constant maintenance and is rendered ineffective if whatever you're trying to stop changes addresses.

Comment: Normally is not possible to block someone only by his ip even if this someone have a static ip that dont change if a router or any other device restart. Most of users have dynamic ip given from ISP that change but may be you can block a range of IP of that ISP for example 123.123.123.* the format depends on what application or firewall you use. There is another scenario, you can try to get the MAC address of the client but the client MAC address will not be available to you except in one special circumstance: if the client is on the same ethernet segment as the server and this is really rare.